# C++: Local reference

Tags: c++, reference, local

I would like to understand what happens in the following code

```
struct A
{
  vector<double> x;
};

void f(A &a)
{
  vector<double> &y = a.x;
}
```

When the function f exits, is a.x destroyed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that references are  not objects. `y` is a *variable*, but not an *object*. It is a reference to the existing object `a.x`, but that object itself is not local to the scope of `f`. So the variable `y` goes out of scope at the end of `f`, but the object to which it refers does not.

Answer (score 4):

No `a.x` is not destroyed. You simply have created a local reference to `a.x` and then the function exits - nothing is changed. Your code effectively does nothing at all.

Comment: I thought that when the function exits, y is destroyed (right?). And since y is a reference to a.x, the latter should be destroyed too. What am I missing?

Comment: @user1598163 y is a reference to `a.x` and `y` will not exist after the function exits. `a.x` exists prior to the function being called, y is created as a reference to it then the function exits. `y` no longer exists but `a.x` does.

Comment: think of a reference as an alias. I can call you Joe (this is a reference), but if I die, only that alias will cease to exist.. it won't kill you.

Comment: @user1598163 `a.x` will persist until the instance `a` is destroyed. Your function just references that member of `a`. `a` still exists after the function exists, and hence so do its members.

Comment: @mathematician1975+Karoly: I appreciate your help. I thought that whatever changes happen to a reference, they are reflected to the target object as well. If that is true, then shouldn't a.x be deleted as well? Apologies if I am becoming pesting...

Comment: If it helps, think of the reference as a pointer. When a pointer goes out of scope, the object it points to is not destructed. A reference looks like an object but is actually just a pointer to one.

Comment: @user1598163 Yes you are right if you make a change to it - if you push a new value to `y` before the function exits, then this is the same as pushing it to `a.x`. However, `y` is just a reference and once it goes out of scope it does not cause `a.x` to be destroyed.

Comment: OK everyone, thinking of it as a pointer helps a lot. Thanks very much for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, when you enter `f()` you locally create a reference `y` to `a.x` that exists independently from `a` and the rest of the world. When you leave `f()` the locally created reference `y` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. The rest of the world stays as it was before you entered `f()`.